# Error using mlogit pkg in R for logistic regression on Clinical dataset

Tags: r, logistic, mlogit

I am a clinicians (limited statistical knowledge) who is trying to use mlogit pkg in R to analyze a clinical dataset, running logistic regression on it. I am trying to ascertain if there is any correlation seen in patients with many vars and heart block (var = block (0s and 1s))

I have a dataset with these variables

```
 [1] "Age"                    "Sex"                    "Race"                       "Obesity"               
 [5] "CAD"                    "HTN"                    "DM"                     "HLD"                   
 [9] "CHF"                    "COPD"                   "Asthma"                 "Thyroid.disorder"      
[13] "Smoking"                "Illicit.drug.use"       "Alcohol"                "INR"                   
[17] "TB"                     "AST"                    "ALT"                    "Cirrhosis"             
[21] "Adenosine"              "Amiodarone"             "Beta.blocker"           "CCB"                   
[25] "Digoxin"                "TCA"                    "SSRI"                   "Antipsychotic"         
[29] "AV.block"               "Bundle.branch.block"    "PAC.PVC"                "Afib"                  
[33] "Other.Arrythmia"        "Nonspecific.ST.wave"    "Anterioseptal..ST.wave" "Anteriolateral.ST.wave"
[37] "Inferior.ST.wave"       "Posterior.ST.wave"      "Axis.deviation"         "Low.voltage"           
[41] "Qt.prolongation"        "Hypertrophy"            "block"
```

Now I have used the mlogit pkg in R

My Code is

```
# Reshaping data
mydata <- mlogit.data(data=mydata, shape="wide", choice="block")

# Creating Model with all Vars
model <- mlogit(data=mydata, formula=block~0|Age+Sex+Race+Obesity+CAD+HTN+DM+HLD+CHF+COPD+Asthma+Thyroid.disorder+Smoking+Illicit.drug.use+Beta.blocker+CCB+Digoxin+TCA+SSRI+Antipsychotic+Hypertrophy+INR+TB+AST+ALT)
```

Generates this error :

```
 Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : 
 Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[43,43] = 0
```

Now if I break the variables into different variables like..

```
model1 <- mlogit(data=mydata, formula=block~0|Age+Sex+Race+Obesity+CAD+HTN+DM+HLD+CHF+COPD+Asthma+Thyroid.disorder+Smoking)
model2 <- mlogit(data=mydata, formula=block~0|Illicit.drug.use+Beta.blocker+CCB+Digoxin+TCA+SSRI+Antipsychotic+Hypertrophy)
model3 <- mlogit(data=mydata, formula=block~0|INR+TB+AST+ALT)
```

IT WORKS without any errors.

But here I would like to know,
how breaking into different models would change my Coefficients?
What should I do to avoid the error and try to incorporate all variables in one model?
How should I interpret my results if break into 3 different models as opposed to one?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: My basic understanding of logistic regression has been summarized here [link](http://dochacks.tumblr.com/post/144585123124/logistic-regression-for-a-medical-researcher)

Comment: The error message is telling you that with all the variables in the model the model can either perfectly match the result (no statistical error) or that you're trying to estimate more parameters than you have data points. How many rows of data do you have?

Comment: As to *"how breaking into different models would change my Coefficients?"* - how would it not? You should probably read some introductions to multivariate linear models. This is not something special about logistic regression, this is a core concept when you have more than one dependent variable. (And about the world.)

Comment: I have about 408 rows or observations.
I understood now that breaking into models will definitely change coefficients as a set of predictors become different.
But how do I solve this? fitting all the predictors in the model so that R can execute it.

Comment: Strongest possibility at this point is that you have independent variables that are perfectly correlated. Maybe look at a pairs plot and figure out what the problems are.

Comment: Thanks.. That probably was the possibility. I used multinom from nnet package instead of using mlogit. And it gave this coefficient for one variable and a warning message in the end.  
`In sqrt(diag(vc)) : NaNs produced`

Comment: The more serious issue is how you are going to interpret the model if you do manage to get it to fit. What can you say about a coefficient which is conditional on the other 41 variables?